# Unable to decompress Bz2 File has Orginal file using Dotnetzip library

Tags: c#, bzip2, gzip

I have File with 10 line, I'm compressing to Bz2 Format, But when i decompress it, I see generated File has only 9 line. There is data loss of 1.5 line. Here is my Code for compressing to Bz2. Im using DotNet zip Library 
https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Following is the code for compression, I'm converting file to UTF-8 and Bz2 File.

```
    static string Compress(string sourceFile, bool forceOverwrite)
    {
        var outFname = fname + ".bz2";

        if (File.Exists(outFname))
        {
            if (forceOverwrite)
                File.Delete(outFname);
            else
                return null;
        }
        long rowCount = 0;
        var output = File.Create(outFname);

        try
        {
              using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fname))
            {
                using (var compressor = new Ionic.BZip2.ParallelBZip2OutputStream(output))
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(compressor, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                     string line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(line);
                        rowCount++;

                        if (rowCount % 100000 == 0)
                            Console.WriteLine("InProgress..Current Row # " + rowCount.ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (output != null)
                output = null;
        }

        //     Pump(fs, compressor);

        return outFname;
    }
```

I tired to change read method like below

```
            // int charsRead;
                    // char[] buffer = new char[2048];
                    // while ((charsRead = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    // {
                    //     writer.Write(buffer, 0, charsRead);
                    //     rowCount++;

                    //     if (rowCount % 100000 == 0)
                    //         Console.WriteLine("InProgress..Current Row # " + rowCount.ToString());
                    // }
```

For Decompression,here is the code

```
    public static string Decompress(string fname, bool forceOverwrite)
    {
        var outFname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fname);
        if (File.Exists(outFname))
        {
            if (forceOverwrite)
                File.Delete(outFname);
            else
                return null;
        }

        using (Stream fs = File.OpenRead(fname),
               output = File.Create(outFname),
               decompressor = new Ionic.BZip2.BZip2InputStream(fs))
            Pump(decompressor, output);

        return outFname;
    }

    private static void Pump(Stream src, Stream dest)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int n;
        while ((n = src.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            dest.Write(buffer, 0, n);

    }
```

During debugging, I see readline is reading data correctly, not sure whether it is bug in this library dll in convert actual file to Bz2 or reading from Bz2 . Please let me know reason for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you get DotNetZip from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

I had to add the following two lines to your Compress method directly after the while loop.

```
writer.Close();
compressor.Close();
```

Without it, your code was throwing an exception. After that, your code worked fine for a 10 line text file that I ran through it. No missing data.